# Not able to compare strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to compare a string with a set of strings stored in an array. Here is the block of code:

```
then(op => {
        if (op[0].probability > FILTER_THRESHOLD) {
          if (FILTER_LIST.indexOf(op[0].className) > 1) {
            console.log("EUREKA! EUREKA! EUREKA!")

            console.log(op[0].className)
            return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
      })
```

The second `if` statement should evaluate to true in some cases but it is not. The return is always false.

`op[0].className` should be a string and I am also able to get the value from `op[0].probability` correctly.

What could be the reason?

I have tried debugging and cannot seem to get why the 'if' statement is not being true.

Here is the FILTER_LIST array:

`var FILTER_LIST = ["Hello", "Please", "Simple"];`

Please advise how I can fix this!

Thank you!

Comment: The classnames are "Hello" "Please" and "Simple".

Comment: So they should match perfectly right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Take a look at the answer below as to why your if logic is flawed.

Answer (score 2):

`indexOf(...) > 1` asks "did it find a match at the third element or later?" You'll get `false` if it matched at index 0 or 1. If you want just "it found one anywhere", you want `!== -1`, `>= 0`, or to use `includes` instead of `indexOf`.

```
if (FILTER_LIST.indexOf(op[0].className) !== -1) {
// or
if (FILTER_LIST.indexOf(op[0].className) >= 0) {
// or
if (FILTER_LIST.includes(op[0].className)) {
```

Comment: Let me check that

Comment: It did not work as expected. The logic is correct but for some reason it is still returning false. What could be the reason??

Comment: @NavenduPottekkat - Your best bet here is to put a breakpoint on the line and look closely at the array and at the string you're checking. Alternatively, please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). My guess is `className` has another class in it, or a space at the beginning, or at the end, etc., etc.

Comment: The problem is I have to build this code. i.e I use parcel to build this js file and that file is run in the browser. In that case, how would I be able to debug?

Comment: @NavenduPottekkat - Use the debugger built into the browser.